# Is it possible to get the name of the method executed in resolver at runtime AppSync?

Tags: aws-appsync

I have an AppSync PIPELINE composed of an *auth-service + business-service*.

I have implemented RBAC in *auth-service*, so based on the operation and the role that the user has, it allows or dennies the execution of the *bussiness-service*.

I need to map the GraphQL Mutation or Query field (method called from the client) to the operation (for example if the user try to do the Mutation: **addUser**, this is the operation).

Is it possible to get the method executed by the client in the resolver at run time? (for example **addUser**, **deletePost**). In order to not have to implement a different auth-service for each of the Queries and Mutations?

Comment: That information is not currently available, but is on our roadmap. I'll be sure to add this as a +1 to this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Similar scenario, here's what I'm doing:

- Before Mapping - Save identity/claims from Cognito etc. to the stash.
- Function Request - Check stash, if unauthorized $util.error, else
  store the operation name and operand details in the stash before
  continuing.
- Function Response - Perform any other filtering or ownership checks
  on the response, $util.error/early return if unauthorized.
- After Mapping - Final transformation of the response or passthrough.

Basically I felt that exposing deep knowledge about an Entity to a generic pipeline auth function was a bad idea, I was more comfortable with an entity's resolver function being aware of what is allowed/disallowed.